# How many threads has simplest WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf

Recently I had a job interview and I was asked:

> How many threads have simple WPF application at start?.

So how many threads have simplest application straight from visual studio project template?
I answered that there is:

1. Main Thread and
2. GC Thread.

So my answer was **two threads at start.** It wasn't the right answer.
Till now i found out that there is *also JIT compiler thread*, but didn't find any solid reference to that.

Could someone enlighten me in this matter? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why would someone ask this question. It sounds like useless trivia to me. /rant

Comment: I don't know an answer to this, nor could I find any. but give a read to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28313933/6611487). This is not relevant to your question but worth some knowledge.

Comment: @Euphoric i guess you might be right.

Comment: this sounds like one of the nonsense questions drawn up by people that aren't technical, to test technical people to try and weed out people who have fakes there CV. don't take it too closely to heart as they have probably just googled wpf threading and noted down what ever number they saw with out actually knowing it its right themselves

Comment: This isn't a nonsense question. Lets say you have a bug in which you are creating many unnecessary threads. You need a baseline to start with, knowing how many threads the most basic WPF application uses is therefore a useful bit of information to know.

Comment: This is a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the the main (dispatcher) thread on which your custom code and any input event handlers are raised by default and a hidden background rendering thread that paints the screen.

This is documented on MSDN:

**Threading Model:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model

Then you also have the GC thread and the finalizer thread and any other house-keeping thread that the CLR may create.

So that would be at least 4 managed threads by default.