# Instantiating the same class multiple times from threads appears as instantiated only once C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm developing an application in C # on WPF.

I need to launch more than once the same MyListWindow class which consists of XAML and the code behind XAML.CS.

The problem is that strange things happen (from my point of view and because of my ignorance).

In particular, I have a main thread that launches a PIPE Server which should launch multiple secondary threads, each of which instantiates a new MyListWindow window.

Strange things happen just when more than one secondary thread is launched from the main thread. First of all he throws me an exception which warns me that the MyListWindow object is already in use by another thread, but it does not make sense, because each secondary thread invokes a new one.

Part of the code is posted below:

```
namespace Kyactus
{
    public partial class App
    {
        private Registration _reg = new Registration();

        public App()
        {
            if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Count() > 1)
            {
                Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length != 2)
                {
                    currentProcess.Kill();
                    return;
                }
                var client = new NamedPipeClientStream("IPC_Context_Menu");
                client.Connect();
                var writer = new StreamWriter(client);
                writer.WriteLine(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]);
                writer.Flush();
                currentProcess.Kill();
            }
            else
            {
                Globals.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
                Globals.MainWindow.Show();
                StartContextMenuListener();
            }
        }

        public void StartContextMenuListener()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(myTask);
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();
        }

        void myTask()
        {
            NamedPipeServerStream server;
            while (true)
            {
                server = new NamedPipeServerStream("IPC_Context_Menu");
                server.WaitForConnection();
                var reader = new StreamReader(server);
                string FileOrFolderFromContextMenu = reader.ReadLine();
                Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    ListUsersContextMenu listWindow = new ListUsersContextMenu(Globals.MainWindow.UsersXAML.Items, FileOrFolderFromContextMenu);
                    listWindow.ShowDialog(); // Thorws: System.InvalidOperationException because object 'listWindow' is property of another thread
                    IList selectedUsers = listWindow.DialogResult();
                    foreach (User selectedUser in selectedUsers)
                    {
                        Client c = new Client();
                        c.invoke(selectedUser.IP.ToString(), FileOrFolderFromContextMenu, selectedUser.ID, selectedUser.Name);
                    }

                });
                t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                t.IsBackground = true;
                t.Start();
                t.Join();
                server.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? I wish I could run the lambda several times.

Comment: as you already included advanced concepts like setting the apartment state, it looks like you know what you're doing :) the root of the problem is the relation of the UI thread (always one, always the same) and your user/background threads - every interaction must be done via the async/await pattern or [Dispatcher.Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28313933/1132334) and this includes showing a new instance of a window.

Comment: You can't use any UI element that Globals.MainWindow creates in the ListUsersContextMenu that you create on another thread. A UI element may only be access from the thread on which it was originally created.